# Stop safari from auto refreshing pages

Tags: mac, firefox, google-chrome, safari

About two days ago, when I visit a particular site in an intranet of my company, the pages I load from there automatically reload every 65 seconds.  I have Mac Book pro and this happens when I use Safari (5.0.5), and not when I use Firefox or Chrome.  I can't recall making any changes to Safari.  I have no plugins installed in Safari.  Any hints on how to resolve this?

Things I have checked:

- No Safari plugins installed.
- No auto refresh meta tag in the html I'm loading.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off JavaScript or load an extension to block JavaScript for that site.

Comment: What for an extension ?

Comment: JavaScript auto-refreshing in Safari but not in Firefox neither in Chrome ? I doubt this.